# Is password necessary in this circumstances?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

When I use below part in the web.config, it gives error

> ```
> (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'John'.)
> ```

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ConnectionString" value="server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=Survey;Integrated     Security=False;User Instance=True;User=John;"/>
</appSettings>
```

But when I open the SQL management studio, I do not enter any password.

Authentication seems Windows Authentication and there are user name and password which are disabled, I cannot enter anything and although the password is empty when I click the connect button, I can connect database but from the asp.net project I cannot connect because I get the Login failed for user error.

How can I solve this problem?

When I wrote `Integrated Security=False,` it is needed to enter password, but it seems empty.
When I wrote `Integrated Security=True`, I get below error:

`"Cannot open database "Survey" requested by the login`. The login failed.
Login failed for user.."

Note: I use SQL Server 2008, asp.net 4.0, and c# programming language.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Integrated Security`, then the current Windows user account is used.  In ASP.NET, this is whatever you have configured for the application pool.

If it's set to `False`, then it will use the `User Id` and `Password` credentials you supply - which must be SQL Server credentials.

Comment: When I use windows user account, it says that: "Cannot open database "Survey" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'John-PC/John'."

Answer (score 0):

If management studio is set to windows authentication you log in using your current windows credentials. you can edit the connection string and add your windows password. or you can set the sql server to windows/sql authentication mixed mode and add a new sql login with a new username and password and use that one instead

Comment: how can I add a new username and password?

Comment: management tools is not installed on the computer i'm currently using, but if you're logged in in management studio and you open the database tree on the side there is a securiy folder with inside a logins folder. rightclick on logins and choose add. in the new windows you can add a new username and password